# Cual es la sintaxis para repetir una funcion en C++?

Tags: c++, sintaxis

Cual es la syntax para que el programa repita nuevamente un texto usando ( if/else Statement )

Como ejemplo escribi un codigo en el cual el sistema le da una serie de indicaciones al usuario, despues le pregunta si quedo entendido, el usuario debe responder ( 1= SI 2= NO ) en caso de que el usuario responda con el #2 quisiera que el sistema le arrojara nuevamente la informacion.

CODE:

```
cout << "Summer School will beging May 25th 2020.\n";
            cout << "The cost of summer school is $100.\n";
            cout << "And classes are from at 9am to 12pm.\n\n";
            int clear;
            cout << "Understood ?\n" << "Yes = 1     No = 2\n";
            cin >> clear;
                if (clear == 1) {
                    cout << "Good! \n See You There :)";
                } else { 
                    cout << "Read the information again.";
                        }
```

Quiero saber que debo usar para que el sitema arroje nuevamente la informacion  y al final elusuario oprima 1 (que si entendio).

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Sabes lo que es un bucle? ¿for, while, do-while? Tienes que hacer un bucle con una condición de salida que se cumpla cuando pulse 1 y continúe dando vueltas si no responde 1. Te recomiendo volver al manual y aprender lo básico con algún ejemplo.

Comment: Muy bien muchas grcias, le dare un repaso nuevamente a ese tema, Tengo poco de haber empezado a estudiar C++. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo que buscas es que pase esto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int clear; //logicamente tienes que sacar la variable del bucle para que el do-while pueda evaluarla desde el principio

do{
  cout << "Summer School will beging May 25th 2020.\n";
  cout << "The cost of summer school is $100.\n";
  cout << "And classes are from at 9am to 12pm.\n\n";

  cout << "Understood ?\n" << "Yes = 1     No = 2\n";
  cin >> clear;

  if (clear == 1) {
    cout << "Good! \n See You There :)";
  } else { 
    cout << "Read the information again.\n\n";
  }
} while (clear == 2);


return 0;
}
```

Es un bucle muy sencillo. Nos alegra que te intereses por el mundo de C++. :)

Recuerda tabular correctamente para que sea más fácil de leer.

Comment: Precisamente esto es lo que requiero, es mucho mas sencilllo que lo que yo hize, muchas gracias, seguire aprendiendo.